# Does MASM assembling multiple source files and linking them together?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I was trying to see if asm language support function based linked like "C" language. E.g. I have got "m.asm":

```
assume cs:code
code segment
start:
  mov ax,20h
  call s
  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
code ends
end start
```

In which "s" is a symbol not existing in the source code, then I've got n.asm file to define a symbol (a label in fact)

```
code segment
s:
  mov bx,4h
  div bx
code ends
```

In fact m.asm fails to compile, telling me that "s" is a symbol not defined. How can I resolve this problem and meet my request?

Comment: http://www.oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-10.html#HEADING10-34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare function `s` as visible to other modules that wish to access it (e.g. via `call`) in `n.asm` using the `public` directive and you need to declare `s` as an external reference using the `extern` directive in `m.asm`.

This is fine for a small number of declarations but if your modules grow to any substantial size you may want to use an `include` header files to manage that.