# MASM: linking 2 asm files together failed: fatal error L1101: invalid object module?

Tags: assembly, compilation, linker, masm

I was trying to compile 2 .asm files using a function call and link them together, the main program(m.asm) is :

```
assume cs: code

  extrn s: near

code segment
start:
  mov ax,20h
  call s
  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
code ends

  end start
```

And the function "s" is define in n.asm:

```
  assume cs: code

  public s

code segment
s:
  mov bx,4h
  div bx
  ret
code ends

  end
```

So in dosbox I used masm to compile them:

```
masm m.asm
masm n.asm
```

No problem, then I try to link them together:

```
link m.obj+n.obj m.exe
```

Now masm gives error:

```
M.EXE : fatal error L1011: invalid object module
 pos: 1 Record type: 4D
```

Why is that? Do I need any special compile/link flags to make it successful?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a really old linker.  Try `link m.obj + n.obj /out:m.exe` or maybe just `link m.obj n.obj /out:m.exe`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MASM assembling multiple source files and linking them together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218712/does-masm-assembling-multiple-source-files-and-linking-them-together) by the exact same poster using the exact same code.

Comment: Not sure I'd call this a duplicate.  There he was getting a compiler error.  Here he's getting a linker error (probably because it's trying to link 'm.exe' into the output).

Comment: I got the answer now: should write: "link m.obj+n.obj , m.exe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the code segment as public in both modules:

CODE SEGMENT PUBLIC 'CODE'
and
CODE SEGMENT PUBLIC 'CODE'

Don't forget to provide for a stack segment:
STACK SEGMENT WORD STACK 'STACK'
DW 10 DUP 4855h
STACK ENDS

I assembled and linked the files with MASM v6.1 : no errors reported!
The exe executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me, I solved the problem by just installing Masm32 instead of Masm,
download and install it then set the program path in variables environment.
Download link:
http://masm32.com/download.htm